# django url ignoring slug argument on request

Tags: regex, django, django-views, django-urls, slug

Django (1.11) app where users can make purchases. trying to give an individual user a purchase view tied to their specific purchase (if purchase[s] exist). However req'ing the purchase view redirects back to the user profile view.

model:

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

class Purchase(models.Model):
    purchase_id = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='purchases')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='purchase_id', default='', unique_with='user', max_length=255)
    date_purchased = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Purchase #{}, user: {}'.format(self.purchase_id, self.user)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.purchase_id:
            purchase_id =  str(uuid.uuid4().int)
            self.purchase_id =  int(purchase_id[-9:])

        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self.purchase_id

        return super(Purchase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

urls:

```
# base profile view
url(r'^user/(?P<username>[0-9a-zA-Z_]*)$', views.user_profile, name="user_profile"),
# purchase view
url(r'^user/(?P<username>[0-9a-zA-Z_]*)/purchase/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', views.user_purchase, name="user_purchase"),
```

purchase view:

```
from .models import User, Purchase

def user_purchase(request, username, slug):

    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

    purchase = get_object_or_404(Purchase, slug=slug, user=user)

    context = {
        'user': user,
        'purchase': purchase
    }

    # also confirmed this html file exists in the correct folder
    return render(request, 'users/user_purchase.html', context)
```

in the base profile template my url is:

```
{% if purchases %}
      {% for p in purchases %}
        <a href="{% url 'user_purchase' user.username p.slug %}">View purchase</a>
      {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

running localhost (local server) on profile view, I can see my dummy purchase and hovering on the url I see the correct route: `localhost:8000/user/user1/purchase/111111111` and if I render {{ p.slug }} it's `111111111`

where I can see in the database (local shell) for Purchase.objects.filter().values() `<QuerySet [{'id': 2, 'purchase_id': 111111111, 'user_id': 1, 'slug': '111111111' ... }]`

yet when I click on the link the request goes to `HTTP GET /user/user1` and I'm redirected back to the base profile view. as far as I can tell I've got the correct url route and it's passing the correct arguments to the request - any reason why the req would ignore the slug arg? anywhere I should research further? thanks